# How do I setup a WIFI router so all connected users can only see this single web server?

Tags: wireless-router, wifi-configuration

It's not really a captive portal. I just need all connected users to see this one specific website, nothing else. No log in or sign in needed.

Any suggestions for the type of WIFI router (cheaper is better) and how it can be set up?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question, (like most "I want function X" questions for home routers) may be to get a router which supports DD-WRT and configure the firewall in DD-WRT to only allow access to the IP of the site in question + DNS).

To make the site work, you could probably get away with a set of rules which readdresses any traffic on port 80 to the IP of the website you want.  (It looks like you can do this using the NAT/QoS tag).  [ Also, block anything except port 80 and 53 traffic ]

[ This will be a 99% solution, you were not clear on "how vital" non-abuse is.  If its absolutely vital you need to lock down DNS and force answers for everything to the IP address you want.  Similarly if there is more then 1 website on the web server and its imperative that only the 1 you want is reachable, you would need to intercept packets with a proxy and rewrite them - which is comparatively difficult ]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.The server does have multiple web folders. I'll need each router to point to one specific folder. How can this be done?

Comment: Practically speaking you would need to code that into your application - it is not a question that can really be done at a router level, nor is it really a "Superuser" question.  (You may want to look at setting up VPN's between the routers and sites so you can identify the IP address they are coming from and act on that).